# Laravel 5: Removing caches from code not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

We have implemented a "make:theme" command and we want to flush the cache after the theme is installed. In Command.php, caches are tried to be removed with

```
Cache::forget('key');
Cache::flush();
```

When refreshing the page in browser, we still get the old cache.

However, when we call "Cache:flush();" method in a controller, IT WORKS!!

Shouldn't cache be removed from code the same as they are when "config:cache: command is called?

Thanks in advance,
Faton

Comment: where do you call `Cache::forget('key');` ?

Comment: Cache::forget() is called within php code (handle method) of a command.

Comment: Sounds like a storage permissions error. `sudo chmod -R 777 storage/*` then try again

Comment: @Option Thanks. I already did it. IT solved the problem with current caches. However, when cached are flushed (which means removed than created) they are owned by www, than I have to chmod 777 them again so I can delete it via php, which is really a headache :(

Answer (score 1):

Call the [cache:clear command](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/artisan#calling-commands-from-other-commands) in the handle method of your custom command you create.

`$exit = Artisan::call('cache:clear');`

Make sure u add a `use Artisan;` to let the autoloader know you need this object.

Comment: The problem seems to be with permissions. Cache files are created with www user, while console commands are run with "operating system"'s user. I chmod 777 all directories, but the problem is still there as long as caches are generated via apache (when a link is accessed form URL)!!

Comment: FYI. Laravel is locking /storage/cache files when creating, something that doesn't happen with bootstrap/cache/config.php

Comment: @FatonSopa right, well then you need to putt the OS user and the www user in the same www-data group. Neve chmod all files and folders to 777, way to risky. Don't do it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm in local server that's why I'm generous with permissions :D.. I'm a little confused with users groups! Laravel cached files have these permissions

"-rw-r--r--  1 _www  staff  12318 Feb 21 15:16 storage/framework/cache/3c/c1/3cc1d5a427a45820b04fe30f78a972b784952460"

I added my user "sopa" to _www group but it didn't help:

"sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a sopa  -t user _www"

Did I mis something?

Comment: @FatonSopa that goes a little over my head, i'm a developer not a sysadmin, you should ask this question on another stack platform and remove this question.